# Множественное редактирование данных PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Имею код для вывода данных в форму:

```
   <form name='form_user".$id_user."' class='forms' method='post' action='update_user.php'>
  <?php 
                      connect();
                     $sql_prava = "SELECT * FROM users";
                     $result_prava = mysql_query($sql_prava);
                while($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_prava)){
                $user_name = $arr['name_user'];
                $otdel_name = $arr['otdel'];
                $pravo = $arr['prava'];
                $id_user = $arr['id'];   
                echo "
                <input type='text' name='user_name' value='".$user_name."' style='width: 200px;' />

                <input type='text' name='name_otdel' value='".$otdel_name."' style='width: 200px;' />

                <select style='width: 250px;' name='pravo'>
                <option value='".$pravo."'>";
                if($pravo == 1){echo "Чтение и редактирование всего";}else if($pravo == 3){echo "Чтение всего";}
                echo "</option>
                <option value='1'>Чтение и редактирование всего</option>
                <option value='4'>Чтение и редактирование своего</option>
                <option value='3'>Чтение всего</option>
                <option value='2'>Чтение своего</option>
                </select>
                ";  
             }
             mysql_close();
?>
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

И обработчик формы:

```
<?php

require_once('checkAuth.php');
connect();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        $name_user =$_POST['user_name'];
        $name_otdel = $_POST['name_otdel'];
        $pravo = $_POST['pravo'];
$update_sql = "UPDATE users SET name_user='$name_user', otdel='$name_otdel', prava='$pravo'";
mysql_query($update_sql) or die("Ошибка вставки" . mysql_error());
header("Location: admin.php");
    }
?>
```

Как реализовать множественное редактирование данных в форме по одной кнопке?

Comment: Что значит "множественное редактирование данных в форме"?

Comment: @cyadvert сразу все записи, которые выведены

Comment: @cyadvert, судя по всему изменение данных нескольких пользователей за раз. Автор, вам надо либо массивы тогда уже передавать (будет коряво, если checkbox'ы будут нужны, разве что явно ключи указывать), либо каждому элементу свой id и name присваивать, либо перехватывать сабмит формы и отправлять на сервер данные так, чтобы там можно было однозначно определить к какому пользователю они относятся.

Comment: как сказал уже @BOPOH создавать массивы с ключом, где ключ id пользователя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо исправить имена полей вот таким образом:

```
            echo "
            <input type='text' name='user[" . $user_id . "][user_name]' value='".$user_name."' style='width: 200px;' />
            <input type='text' name='user[" . $user_id . "][name_otdel]' value='".$otdel_name."' style='width: 200px;' />
            <select style='width: 250px;' name='user[" . $user_id . "][pravo]'>";
```

В этом случае `POST` будет иметь форму

```
$_POST["user"]=>Array(
    [{user_id}]=>Array(
        [user_name]=>'содержимое поле user_name для пользователя user_id',
        [user_otdel]=>'содержимое поле user_otdel для пользователя user_id',
        [pravo]=>'содержимое поле pravo для пользователя user_id',
    ),
    [{user_id2}]=>Array(
        [user_name]=>'содержимое поле user_name для пользователя user_id',
        [user_otdel]=>'содержимое поле user_otdel для пользователя user_id',
        [pravo]=>'содержимое поле pravo для пользователя user_id',
    ),
    [{user_id3}]=>Array(
        [user_name]=>'содержимое поле user_name для пользователя user_id',
        [user_otdel]=>'содержимое поле user_otdel для пользователя user_id',
        [pravo]=>'содержимое поле pravo для пользователя user_id',
    ),
);
```

`{user_id}`, `{user_id2}` и `{user_id3}` - это `id` ваших пользователей

Ну а дальше в обработчике пробегаетесь по массиву и обновляете данные:

```
    foreach($_POST["user"] as $user_id=>$user_data) {
        $name_user =$user_data['user_name'];
        $name_otdel = $user_data['name_otdel'];
        $pravo = $user_data['pravo'];
        $update_sql = "UPDATE users SET name_user='$name_user', otdel='$name_otdel', prava='$pravo' WHERE user_id=" . $user_id;
        mysql_query($update_sql) or die("Ошибка вставки" . mysql_error());
    }
```